# Best Java obfuscator?

Tags: java, obfuscation

I am developing a security software and want to obfuscate my java code so it will become impossible to reverse engineer. What is the most reliable java obfuscator ?

Comment: I had some colleagues who created some heavily obfuscated code. But that was not their intention.

Comment: @Mnementh: it is enough to make reverse engineering prohibitively expensive for your particular app.

Comment: @Robert Harvey: Not sure why did you thought this question was not constructive. It is related to programming and in my opinion it is as good question as any other programming questions

Answer (score 110, accepted):

First, you really need to keep in mind that it's **never** impossible to reverse-engineer something. Everything is hackable. A smart developer using a smart IDE can already get far enough.

Well, you can find [here](http://java-source.net/open-source/obfuscators) a list. ProGuard is pretty good. I've used it myself, but only to "minify" Java code.

Comment: @BalusC: So what tool do you use to obfuscate java code? you do obfuscate your java code, dont' you?

Comment: @Thinhbk Obfuscation makes it harder to get useful stack traces.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen: Agree. IMO, obfuscation will make stack traces become mostly useless. In that case, I'm using some trick with the log msg, which can help.

Comment: @Thinhbk Proguard generates a map to translate obfucated stack traces back to the original code. Otherwise, as you said, stack traces would become useless (but who gets uncaught exceptions anyway... ;-))

Comment: @Matthieu: Is it possible to translate stack trace backed to original code automatically? It would be great, and new for me. I just know translate back manually can be difficult if the code base is huge.

Comment: @Thinhbk [it seems so](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/retrace/examples.html)

Comment: @Matthieu You still need the stack traces in case of something unexpected - caught or not.

Answer (score 41):

If a computer can run it, a sufficiently motivated human can reverse-engineer it.

Comment: How many people can read obfuscated code and understand the logic? I have lots of engineer friend and they can't do that. Only John Nash can do this ;)

Comment: @kodmanyagha If they were motivated enough they would learn it. It is not hard.

Comment: In mathematical sense, it is possible to run without a way to reverse-engineer it. This is what homomorphic encryption is about, but there are quite a few obstacles that need to be solved to make it practically usable on computer software as opposed to SaaS. We are moving there slowly. Seminal works of Gentry on fully homomorphic encryption and "mathematical jigsaw puzzles" by Amit Sahai et al. made a huge leap in that direction. There is just one missing element (which I call a "barrier function") that would make the whole scheme feasible. What's impossible now will be possible in the future.

Comment: @kodmanyagha if the motivation is strong enough, a human being can read and analyze through any obfuscated code. Someone even wrote a program that read Java/Javasript grammer and rename all the variables to be more readable name and then re-read the modified source. I don't think obfuscation can really protect the codes.

Answer (score 30):

Check out my article **[Protect Your Java Code - Through Obfuscators And Beyond [Archived]](https://web.archive.org/web/20161217190546/http://www.excelsior-usa.com/articles/java-obfuscators.html)** for a discussion of obfuscation vs three other ways to make the reverse engineering of your apps more expensive, and a collection of links to tools and further reading materials.

Comment: This is what I actually need. I want to write PHP obfuscator for my projects. The logic is same everywhere. Thanks...

Comment: Cool and extensive article about Java obfuscation and Software collection.

Answer (score 15):

I think that Proguard is the best. It is also possible to integrate it with your IDE (for example NetBeans). However, consider that if you obfuscate your code it could be difficult to track problems in your logs..

Comment: +1 for "consider that if you obfuscate your code it could be difficult to track problems in your logs". Just when you thought that debugging was hard enough...

Comment: A good obfuscator that change names and line number information should produce a log with which to reverse the process. This way at least stack traces remain useful for obfuscated binaries.

Comment: ProGuard creates such reverse files for debugging. :-)

Answer (score 11):

As said elsewhere on here, [proguard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/) is good, but what might not be known is that there is also a third-party maven plugin for it here http://pyx4me.com/pyx4me-maven-plugins/proguard-maven-plugin/...I've used them both together and they're very good.

Answer (score 10):

I used [Allatori](http://www.allatori.com/) and it did its job pretty well.

Answer (score 8):

It is true that it is always possible to reverse engineer some code, just like it is impossible to protect a house in order so nobody can ever steal from it.
That does not keep me from locking the door, though.
Actually, I am not in the java world, I use [BitHelmet](http://www.bithelmet.com) for .net.

Comment: +1 to bring you back to net 0. This answer is not unhelpful.

Answer (score 7):

I used to work with [Klassmaster](http://www.zelix.com/klassmaster/) in my previous company and it works really well and can integrate pretty good with build systems (maven support is excellent). But it's not free though.

Answer (score 6):

We've had much better luck encrypting the jars rather than obfuscating. We use [Classguard](http://www.jsecurity.net/).

Comment: If you have not read "Cracking Java byte-code encryption" (http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javaqa/2003-05/01-qa-0509-jcrypt.html) by Vladimir Roubtsov, you may wish to do that now.

Comment: The link does not working anymore.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know for sure if the solution is safe, but about the [ClassGuard](http://zenofx.com/classguard/) solution, it's interesting to read the article and the comment at: http://www.javaworld.com/community/?q=node/1604#comment-12296

Comment: And another alternative that also uses native code instead of defineClass is [JarCrypt](http://www.componio.com/products/jinstaller/jarcryp/)

Comment: An article teaching how to crack [ClassGuard](http://zenofx.com/classguard/): http://setrst.blogspot.com/2010/04/classguard-unguarded.html. I just don't know if this still works on the latest version.

Comment: Bot links are not working anymore.