# How to protect a java application from reverse-engineering or code stealing?

Tags: java, obfuscation, reverse-engineering, source-code-protection

I want to reveal my desktop java application to public, but I'm not sure how to protect it from reverse-engineering or source code stealing?

Is it possible to convert the application to an exe file? and if it is, wouldn't that be enough to protect it?

Comment: Determined people will always find a way to reverse engineer your code.

Comment: *"I'm no't sure how to protect it"*  Make it crappy (the default for people asking this question) and nobody will bother to reverse engineer it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best Java obfuscator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537568/best-java-obfuscator)

Answer (score 5):

If it's really worth someone's time to reverse engineer your source from the binary, they will.  You might be able to make it slightly harder, but never impossible.

Comment: I think you mean "reverse engineer your binary".

Comment: @Oil, I intended it to mean "reverse engineer your source *from your binary* with the latter implied. If it wasn't obvious, I'll correct it. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a Java Obfuscator such as [ProGuard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/).

> ProGuard is a free Java class file shrinker, optimizer, obfuscator, and preverifier. It detects and removes unused classes, fields, methods, and attributes. It optimizes bytecode and removes unused instructions. **It renames the remaining classes, fields, and methods using short meaningless names**. Finally, it preverifies the processed code for Java 6 or for Java Micro Edition.

Comment: ProGuard makes things quite painful for would-be reverse-engineers. Imho, this is about as good as you can do.

Answer (score 3):

A Java executable and a native executable are both just a bunch of machine code (with optional annotations and stuff).  So there's essentially no difference in terms of how easy it is to reverse-engineer.

If you are compiling with javac, you can use the `-g:none` flag to eliminate all debug info from being compiled into the executable.