# How to work with changing GUI's in NetBeans Java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans

I'm creating an application to test my Java skills, and I am using NetBeans because of the GUI builder because I'm not quite used to laying GUI's out by hand yet (the GUI is in Swing). I have a simple login form, that if the login information is correct, disappears and is replaced with different GUI elements. How could I make the second page that replaces the login page with the GUI builder?

Comment: Take a look at [How to use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)

Comment: Take a look at [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15908275/how-can-i-add-a-login-screen-to-an-existing-java-swing-program). It's a simple login using a custom `JDialog`.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want a [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html). However, this might be a dup of [Java Swing: How can I implement a login screen before showing a JFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7323086/java-swing-how-can-i-implement-a-login-screen-before-showing-a-jframe)