# Java JDBC Login with user-provided username/password

Tags: java, jdbc, authentication

I'm trying to make a login screen that uses users and passwords of DBMS. To clarify: there is no a table of users, only the database access rights.

```
private String username = "root";
private String password = "root";
private String classname = "org.postgresql.Driver";
private String url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/bd";
```

To be clear, I want to obtain user and password from user input, not to hardcode them.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: where are the "inputs"? Are you thinking a Dialog maybe? And then grab the values and pass them into you connection?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I add a login screen to an existing Java Swing program?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15908275/how-can-i-add-a-login-screen-to-an-existing-java-swing-program)

Comment: The problem is that in the process of make a connection with DBMS it needs to receive a username and password. In all codes that I lookup, it is hardcode in the the database class, and I want it to come from inputs. I already have the inputs, I only need to know how to set up the connection dynamic.

Comment: @Jan Yes, that is it. I'm now only need to find how to grab and pass the values to the connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need a connection for some given user and pass use:

```
public Connection getConnection(String user, String pass) {
  String url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/bd";
  return DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
}
```

Linked in some code to show how it could be done:

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class DynamicConnection {

    protected String user = null;
    protected String pass = null;

    protected String url;

    public DynamicConnection(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        while(user == null || pass == null) {
            askForUsernamePassword();
        }
        return DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
    }

    private void askForUsernamePassword() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2,2));
        panel.add(new JLabel("Username"));
        JTextField tf = new JTextField();
        panel.add(tf);
        panel.add(new JLabel("Password"));
        JPasswordField pf = new JPasswordField();
        panel.add(pf);
        if(JOptionPane.OK_OPTION == JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, panel)) {
            user = tf.getText().trim();
            pass = pf.getText().trim();
        }       
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Connection con = new DynamicConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/bd").getConnection();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```