# Best way to protect java code from reverse - engineering

Tags: java, security, obfuscation

Which is the best way today to protect java-code from reverse - engineering? Price is not important. Important is quality.
I read [Best Java obfuscator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537568/best-java-obfuscator) and other such question. Differense of my question is that i accept any ideas. I don't need exactly "obfuscator". I have some logic writen in java. People will use it but they must not reach source code to sell it as it's own. For example make web-service is good idea for that and not pesent in [Best Java obfuscator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537568/best-java-obfuscator).
And also all solutions i found was old. Maybe something new developed.

Comment: Java *code*, or a compiled Java *binary*?

Comment: Perhaps he meant java _byte_ code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even compiling the code can be reverse engineered (harder of course)

I suggest you make it a service which can be access across the web.  This way the critical code is on your server and not accessible to client.

Note: even then you can reverse engineer a program from looking at what it does or reading its documentation.

BTW: The first version of Q-DOS/MS-DOS was based on the manual for CPM without access to a running example, just from reading the manual.  Unfortunately the writer changed `/` to `\` for paths making DOS/Windows the only OS to do this.

Comment: And a "clean room" reverse engineering is legal, too