# Proguard alternative for obfuscating android apps using precompiled third party libraries

Tags: java, android, obfuscation, proguard

I have tried ProGuard many times and spent a lot of time on configuring it to no avail in the past year or so.  It seems to have some inherent limitations related to pre-compiled third-party libraries as explained in its document. ProGuard document nicely provides [a long list of alternatives](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#alternatives.html). Instead of trying them one by one, I am here to see if any could share successful experiences with some of them.  I only need something to obfuscate java code. Code shrinking and optimization are nice to have, but not required.

Comment: Are you looking for only free alternatives ?

Comment: Yes, preferably, but I am willing to purchase a commercial one if I cannot find a free one. What I need is really simple - obfuscating my code. Pre-compiled libraries can be excluded.

Comment: After getting tired or proguard, I tested few evaluation version of the commercial ones. The best one at average cost came out to be [DashO](http://www.preemptive.com/products/dasho/overview). Allatori's algorithm had been cracked already. You can also give one by [SemDesigns](http://www.semdesigns.com/Products/Obfuscators/). Their examples are pretty good but I was unable to make the demo version run. You can see many answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537568/best-java-obfuscator which are usually personal experience of the tool.

Comment: http://www.excelsior-usa.com/articles/java-obfuscators.html  is also a good read.

Comment: yGuard is your choice