# How to convert java sourcecode to bytecode?

Tags: java, android-studio, byte, bytecode

I want to know if there are any ways to convert my java code to byte in android studio to save my code from revercing
If its possible to do that then i will add the key of converting the byte to java again in my server and only if the user logged in
Is that possible to do ?
If yes then how can i do it?

Comment: Is this what you mean? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537568/best-java-obfuscator

Comment: Scary wombat thanks